# Saving same length table regardless of length

Tags: r

I assume my problem is rather simple, but at the moment I just can't figure it out.

I have a vector with different kind of values

```
vector <- c(1, 3, , , , ab)
```

which should result in a table like this

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  3  NA NA NA ab
```

or

```
vector <- c(1, 3, 4, , 5, ab)
```

which should result in a table like this

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  3  4  NA 5  ab
```

Therefore, the goal would be to put every variable in the same column of a table regardless of the length of the vector.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't providing lists, you try to provide a vector. But nevertheless for both when creating lists or vectors the arguments must not be empty: `list <- c(1, 3, NA, NA, NA, "ab")
is(list)

mylist <- list(1, 3, NA, NA, NA, "ab")
is(mylist)`

Comment: Please use `dput()` to give a reproducible example.